# How can i figure out an algorithm by comparing input and output?

Tags: reverse-math

I have a bunch of input numbers and output numbers that were run through an algorithm that I don't know. What is the approach for discovering the algorithm that generated the outputs? I assume this is possible by comparing the input to the output, so here are some random examples:

```
376492 = 648442463866
142731 = 643864412342
548437 = 838302054282
728439 = 834664368782
935765 = 050587050384
```

I'm aware that the algorithm is something very simple, like taking each number in the input and doing simple math like multiplication by single digits or such, then taking a digit from the sum and putting it all together with the result of a different operation or something like that.

I see so far that each digit of input results in two digits of output, as the
function requires a 6 digit number and always returns a 12 digit number.

Also tried a few of these these inputs because they show patterns, maybe it'll make it easier to deduce the algorithm:

`565656 = 030303030303`
(interestingly, input of `656565` gave the same output as above.)

```
000000 = 000000000000
010101 = 000000000000
333333 = 696969696969
888888 = 666666666666
999999 = 686868686868
222222 = 646464646464
111111 = 414141414141
121212 = 828282828282
```

So, bottom line, my question is: Mathematically, How do i go about to deduce the algorithm -?-

[Please keep in mind that I am a noob, and don't understand advanced mathematical expressions! Thank you.]

Comment: There is not unique function that will produce those input-output pairs.

Comment: There isn't even a unique polynomial that will produce them.

Comment: Do you know what kind of function does produce this numbers? Quadratic, exponential or linear function?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example (not unique)
$$f(x)=\cases{648442463866, x=376492\\643864412342, x=142731\\838302054282
, x=548437\\834664368782, x=728439\\050587050384, x=935765\\0, {\rm otherwise}}$$

Comment: +1. (Whenever I see one of these very-literal-mathematician answers, I picture the face of the second guy in [this comic](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2011-04-08).)

Comment: That is funny. Thanks for the laugh